# Unable to send HTML to mail by DT package in R

Tags: r, r-markdown, dt

I have a HTML file created by DT package by using this code:

`saveWidget(report_temp, 'report.html')`

But I couldn't send it to email as following code:

`

```
library(mailR)
sender <- "SENDER@gmail.com"
recipients <- c("RECIPIENT@gmail.com")
send.mail(from = sender,
          to = recipients,
          subject = "Subject of the email",
          body = "report.html",
          smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.gmail.com", port = 465, 
                      user.name = "YOURUSERNAME@gmail.com",            
                      passwd = "YOURPASSWORD", ssl = TRUE),
          authenticate = TRUE,
          send = TRUE)
```

`

The recipient just gets an email with source code.

[image]

But if I use Rmarkdow to create HTML file and then I send it to email, email will show all HTML content (not source code).

[image]

I don't want to use Rmarkdown because I wanna create table with color,...
Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

`html=TRUE` in `send.mail(`

Comment: I did but now I got an error as folllow:
Error: EmailException (Java): Building the MimeMessage failed

Comment: Is it full error or there is additional text? (additionaly `inline = TRUE`, also change nothing?)

Comment: also add `debug=TRUE` to see where problem